# Prestashop - calculated field in backoffice table form

Tags: module, prestashop-1.6

I would like to add a "virtual" field to a Prestashop 1.6 custom table in the back office. The field indice_calculo_pvp2 should not be saved into the database, as it is a calculated from the values of indice_calculo_pvp and precio_venta_recomendado. What would be the correct way to implement this?

My code is as follows :

```
public function renderList() {
    $this->addRowAction('edit');
    $this->addRowAction('delete');

    $this->fields_list = array(
        'id_product_price' => array(
            'search' => false,
            'title' => 'ID'
        ),
        'precio_coste' => array(
            'title' => 'Precio coste',
            'search' => false,
            'callback' => 'callback_format_price',
            'suffix' => '€'
        ),
        'indice_calculo_pvp' => array(
            'title' => 'Indice de cálculo PVP',
            'search' => false,
            'callback' => 'callback_format_price',
            'suffix' => '%'
        ),
        'indice_calculo_pvp2' => array(
            'title' => 'Indice de cálculo PVP2',
            'search' => false,
            'callback' => 'callback_calculate_pvp',
            'suffix' => '%'
        ),
        'precio_venta_recomendado' => array(
            'title' => 'Precio de venta recomendado con IVA',
            'search' => false,
            'callback' => 'callback_format_price',
            'suffix' => '€'
        )
    );

    return parent::renderList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use calculation in your SQL SELECT query for the list. I don't know what your calculation formula and your SELECT query is but example of this:

```
$this->_select = 'a.indice_calculo_pvp / a.precio_venta_recomendado AS indice_calculo_pvp2';
```

Comment: I also commented below... I'm not sure how I would do that, can I just write the select as you put it?

Comment: Thank you, I just put it the way you did and it worked! I'll try to debug the code to understand how this works internally.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- You can use a callback function as in your code:

  public function callback_calculate_pvp($id, $tr)
  {
      return $tr['indice_calculo_pvp'] * $tr['precio_venta_recomendado'];
  }
- You can use a virtual column in your field list `indice_calculo_pvp2` and set the value in your SQL query or in getList override function (as ProductController do with price).

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new to Prestashop... how would I do these things, could you give a short example (how do I add the callback to the fields list -- the idea is to add a new field apart from the existing one)?